# CategoryRouteHandler() reference

Tags: c#, .net, routes

Here is the example I see everywhere for routing without mvc.

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.Add(new System.Web.Routing.Route
        (
             "Category/{action}/{categoryName}"
             , new CategoryRouteHandler()
        ));
    }

Problem:

CategoryRouteHandler assemble can not be found.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem?
I have added System.Web.Routing but that does not solve the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It references a custom class that would need to create.  The class needs to implement the IRouteHandler.   An example of this is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668202.aspx)